# Active Admin with join table relation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

I am configuring Active Admin. Everything is running apart from a join table, which connects the magazine resource with the keyword resource. One magazine is defined by multiple keywords and a keyword can define multiple magazines.

I have two models:

```
### models/magazine.rb

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :colour, :cover_alt, :description, :number, :short, :title_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords, :join_table => "magazines_keywords" 
    belongs_to :title, :class_name => "Keyword", :foreign_key => "title_id"
end


### models/keywords.rb

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :word, :description

  has_and_belongs_to_many :magazines, :join_table => "magazines_keywords"
end
```

And a join table:

```
### models/magazines_keyword.rb
class MagazinesKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :magazine_id, :keyword_id

  belongs_to :magazine
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```

This setting works for the views of my rails app, and I have the index and show section of my AA magazine resource working, but the form (for new and edit) does not work:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Magazine do
    menu :priority => 1

    form do |f|
        f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
        f.inputs "Magazine Details" do
            f.input :title_id, :label => 'Title', :as => :select, :collection => Keyword.all.map{ |u| ["#{u.word.capitalize}", u.id] }
            f.inputs :magazines_keywords do
                f.has_many : magazines_keywords do |s|
                    s.input :keyword, :as => :select, :multiple => true, :collection => MagazinesKeyword.all.map { |u| ["#{u.keyword.word.capitalize}", u.id] }
                end
            end
        end
        f.actions
    end

    show do
        panel "Magazine Details" do
            attributes_table_for magazine do
                row "Keywords", :keyword do |m|
                    m.keywords.map { |d| d.word }.join(", ").html_safe
                end
            end
        end
        active_admin_comments
    end
end
```

When running the app i get `NoMethodError in Admin/magazines#edit`

Where `/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb line #1` raises `undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass`

I can display all the keywords in the form section with:

```
f.input :magazines_keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :multiple => true, :collection => MagazinesKeyword.all.map{ |u| ["#{u.keyword.word.capitalize}", u.id] }
```

But when I try to write them it does not work. Editing the values does not work either.

Where am I missing something? How can I get this working?

****UPDATE****

After some work I got the following solution:

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Saft Details" do
        f.input :title_id, :label => 'Title', :as => :select, :collection => Keyword.all.map{ |u| ["#{u.word.capitalize}", u.id] }
        f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => {:multiple => true}
    end
    f.actions
end
```

And as suggested:

```
f.input :keywords, :as => :check_boxes, :input_html => {:multiple => true} do
    f.has_many :keywords do |s|
        s.input :keyword, :collection => Keyword.all.map { |kw| ["#{kw.word.capitalize}", kw.id] }
        end
end
```

With both solutions I am able to write a new Magazine entry and get the association written to the join table, unfortunately it displays `#<Keyword:0x10c858858>` in the form and not the word. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveAdmin is quite smart to understand what you are trying to do. So you should ignore `MagazinesKeyword` and go straight to `Keyword` model.
So you should change this:

```
f.has_many :magazines_keywords do |s|
  s.input :keyword, :as => :select, :multiple => true, :collection => MagazinesKeyword.all.map { |u| ["#{u.keyword.word.capitalize}", u.id] }
end
```

with this:

```
f.has_many :keywords do |s|
  s.input :keyword, :as => :select, :multiple => true, :collection => Keyword.all.map { |kw| ["#{kw.word.capitalize}", kw.id] }
end
```

Active admin will handle `MagazinesKeyword` by himself.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Indeed `MagazinesKeyword` is not necessary. I had already figured out some sort of a solution, but your suggestion is much better. I currently can write an entry, but the form does not display the keyword, but only `#<Keyword:0x10c858858>`. I will update my question accordingly.